# Scroll by visual line in `centered-cursor-mode`?

Tags: scrolling, visual-line-mode

Mouse scrolling with `visual-line-mode` in `centered-cursor-mode` is jumpy as anything when you're writing prose. A single line of text can be 10 or more visual lines.

Editing in `refill-mode` or `auto-fill-mode` sort of solve the problem but bring on their own set of issues, either by adding linebreaks where they don't belong, or by messing with the text editing.

Comment: What's the question? You seem to be reporting a bug (?). For that, please use `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: You are right @Drew, in the 7 hours since I posted this question, I actually ended up learning how to make minor modes and made my own clone of `centered-cursor-mode` which has the expected behavior. I have never done anything like that before so it was a great learning experience! Sorry for asking in the wrong place btw.

Comment: In that case, please consider deleting the question. And glad you were able to find what you needed, and that you had a great learning adventure! That's the fun of Elisp.